# Retrieve data after pressing submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="chat-input-holder">
         <textarea class="chat-input"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" value="Send" class="message-send"/>
     </div>
```

How to retrieve data in textarea field after clicking on submit button. Using jquery, ajax?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Jquery and ajax is one of your options, yes, but not the only one

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```js
function getdata(Event){
  Event.preventDefault()
  let chatInput = $('#chat-input').val(); 
  $('#result').text(chatInput)
}
$('#message-send').click(getdata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="chat-input-holder"> <!-- replace div with form -->
   <textarea class="chat-input" id="chat-input"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Send" id="message-send" class="message-send"/>
</form>
<p> for the example we will place the text on the div bellow. but use the data however you like</p>
<div id='result'>
</div>
```

Note that I changed the div tag into a form tag, and added some IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a solution using jQuery. The output is currently store in a `div` with `id="out"`, you can customize the code.

```js
document.forms["chat-input-holder"].addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let text = $(".chat-input").val();
    $("#out").html(text);       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="chat-input-holder">
         <textarea class="chat-input"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" value="Send" class="message-send"/>
</form>

<div id="out"></div>
```